# ASP.NET Custom Validator | Check unique name with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to create a custom validator to check if a name is unique.
It seems the server side validation won't be executed. How can I fix this ?

You can find the ASP code and code behind here: http://pastebin.com/biYqMT23

Comment: Please include the code in your post and not just link to an external site.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it my modifying your button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddCategory" runat="server" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="GroupAddCategory" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="ButtonAddCategory_Click" OnClientClick="return Page_ClientValidate('GroupAddCategory');" />
```